# Windows Phone Navigation code error

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

where am I going wrong here?

```
private void lstCars_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string currCar = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as string;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewCarDetails.xaml?info=" + currCar, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

here is the page im trying to navigate to

```
        public ViewCarDetails(string registrationNum)
    {
         //stuff
    }
```

and here is the code that the program jumps to when I get an error (in App.xaml.cs)

```
        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

ive checked the URI but no typos
Thank you

Comment: What is the value of currCar? Try passing currCar like so: Uri.EscapeUriString(currCar)

Comment: cannot find anything wrong in the code. The code for navigation is correct. Check the location of your xaml file. it might be in another folder

Comment: Try adding, NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/ViewCarDetails.xaml?info=" + currCar, UriKind.Relative));

Comment: I'm guessing the ViewCarDetailsView has no default constructor and the navigation API can't create an instance for it. I'm also guessing that you cant pass URI queries in a constructor of a view. You need to use the event and the navigationcontext for it.

Comment: Please inspect the exception in the EventArgs and tell us what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your are passing a parameter via NavigationService and ViewCarDetails class constructor is expecting a parameter that you are not passing through.

To solve it you have to create a constructor with no parameters and take the parameter you are passing through navigationservice from NavigatedTo event as follow:

```
public ViewCarDetails() 
    { 
         //stuff 
    }
```

and

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string registrationNum = string.Empty;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("index", out registrationNum))
        {
                         //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Try it out and let us know,

ADDED:

```
public class ViewCarDetails : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private string registrationNum;

    public ViewCarDetails() 
        { 
             //stuff 
        } 
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            registrationNum = string.Empty;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("index", out registrationNum))
            {
                             //do stuff
            }
        }
    //other methods and properties
}
```

regards,

Comment: im a little confused. im new to all this. where do i use onnavigatedto? how am I getting registration number to the ViewCarDetails constructor? Thank you

Comment: check the answer again. added more code. forget the constructors. With WP7 you are navigating between pages, not calling referenced objects.

Comment: kk :) all fixed. I put all code in the constructor into the navigate method you gave me and now I can use the registration number to make a request :)